# How do I delete an inherited branch policy in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

How can I edit or delete this inherited branch policy? I don't know how it got created and I cannot find anywhere to modify it.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Open project settings->Repositories->click the tab Policies->check the Branch Policies part->click *all branches, then you could delete it. Check the pic below.

[image]

Or you could click the button Inheritance and then you could delete it.

[image]

Comment: On your first screenshot, the vertical ellipsis is not displayed on my UI.

Clicking on the "Inheritance" is what my second screenshot in the OP shows and doesn't allow for me to do anything.

Comment: It seems that you do not have enough permission to change it, you could contact the Org PCA member or project admin to change it.

Comment: In my case, I had added the Policy at project level.  I first had to delete the project-level policy to be able to create different policies for different repositories within the project.